# Unable to login to Ubuntu 20.04 Server

Tags: server, login, remote-login

Team,

I am Unable to login to Ubuntu 20.04 Server as post entering user credentials it again comes back to login screen.
I tried with both local as well as domain credentials but same result.

Need assistance on resolving the issue without formatting or redeploying the VM as that would be the last option as its a Production Server.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Try to login with ssh and check why the login fails